# Trouble understanding holonomic dual basis

Tags: differential-geometry

I saw a post earlier and it made me a bit confused, so I looked into it and I have some questions about a paper I saw. It said since a tangent vector can be defined $u=d/dλ$ where λ is the parameter of the curve it is tangent to, and $dx^μ$ is the set of basis one forms, when the vector acts on the basis it gives $u(dx^μ)=dx^μ/dλ$. But I'm confused how they got that last result. Shouldn't it be $u(dx^μ)=d(dx^μ/dλ)$, or something of the sort? Where does that extra differential on the top go?

Answer (score 0):

The curve is the map $\gamma:t\mapsto x$

The push-forward map is defined for tangents, $\gamma_*:u=\tfrac{d}{dt} \mapsto \sum_i\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$

I take your "vector acting on 1-form" to mean the duality pairing $(\gamma_*u, dx^\mu)$ and to mean $dx^\mu(\gamma_*u)$, i.e. a 1-form acting on a tangent rather.

It follows that, $dx^\mu(\gamma_*u)=dx^\mu(\sum_i\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})=\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}.$